# Nginx Unable To Pas Custom Header To Proxy

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm running Nginx/1.17.5 and wish to pass a custom header with an underscore to a proxy.

If the underscore is removed from the header (x-test instead of x_test), then the header passes through.

Here is the configs

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    access_log /dev/stdout main;

    location /ping {
        return 200 'pong';
    }

    proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    underscores_in_headers on;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://example.com:443;
        add_header x_test $http_x_test always;
    }
}
```

Works

```
curl -X POST 'https://example.com/upstream-app/ \
-H 'Accept: application/json' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'x-test: 7359af9c-a191-41b7-aeab-a3389e1c5e1e' \
--data '{
"body": "VALID",
"from": "99999",
}'
```

Fails

```
curl -X POST 'https://example.com/upstream-app/ \
-H 'Accept: application/json' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'x_test: 7359af9c-a191-41b7-aeab-a3389e1c5e1e' \
--data '{
"body": "VALID",
"from": "99999",
}'
```

Any ideas / pointers on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For this to work, you will have to use tpc loadbalancing by using the [ngx_stream_core_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_core_module.html)

Since you intend to use SSL termination to a backend server, and not in the internet-facing load balancer, you will have to use SSL-passthrough which can be done by the stream module.

Try this:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
  upstream example-http {
    server example.com:80;
  }
  server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    access_log /dev/stdout main;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
      proxy_set_header Connection "";
      add_header    x_test $http_x_test always;
      proxy_redirect     off;
      proxy_connect_timeout  60;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_pass_request_headers on;
      underscores_in_headers on;
      proxy_pass http://example-http$request_uri;
    }
    location /ping {
        return 200 'pong';
    }
  }
}
stream {
  upstream example-https {
    server example.com:443;
  }

  server {
    proxy_protocol on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    listen 443;
    proxy_pass example-https;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#Fix

Updated the proxy.conf to

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    access_log /dev/stdout main;

    location /ping {
        return 200 'pong';
    }

    underscores_in_headers on;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://example.com:443;
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    }
}
```

Then on the Docker container install TcpDump and run the following to inspect all GET and POST headers and also include headers with underscores, as per the regex. NB the command below assumes Docker is running on port 80, set to correct port number.

```
stdbuf -oL -eL /usr/sbin/tcpdump -A -s 10240 "tcp port 80 and (((ip[2:2] - ((ip[0]&0xf)<<2)) - ((tcp[12]&0xf0)>>2)) != 0)" | egrep -a --line-buffered ".+(GET |HTTP\/|POST )|^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+: " | perl -nle 'BEGIN{$|=1} { s/.*?(GET |HTTP\/[0-9.]* |POST )/\n$1/g; print }'
```